# Why in argparse, a 'True' is always 'True'?

Tags: python, argparse

Here is the simplest Python script, named test.py:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--bool', default=True, type=bool, help='Bool type')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.bool)
```

But when I run this code on the command line:

```
python test.py --bool False
True
```

Whereas when my code reads `'--bool', default=False`, the argparse runs correctly.

Why?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are not passing in the `False` object. You are passing in the `'False'` string, and that's a string of non-zero length.

Only a string of length 0 tests as false:

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('Any other string is True')
True
>>> bool('False')  # this includes the string 'False'
True
```

Use a [`store_true` or `store_false` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) instead. For `default=True`, use `store_false`:

```
parser.add_argument('--bool', default=True, action='store_false', help='Bool type')
```

Now omitting the switch sets `args.bool` to `True`, using `--bool` (with no further argument) sets `args.bool` to `False`:

```
python test.py
True

python test.py --bool
False
```

If you *must* parse a string with `True` or `False` in it, you'll have to do so explicitly:

```
def boolean_string(s):
    if s not in {'False', 'True'}:
        raise ValueError('Not a valid boolean string')
    return s == 'True'
```

and use that as the conversion argument:

```
parser.add_argument('--bool', default=True, type=boolean_string, help='Bool type')
```

at which point `--bool False` will work as you expect it to.

Comment: The standard library function `distutils.util.strtobool()` function can be used instead of `boolean_string()` and also supports strings like "yes" and "no" (although it returns an int of 0 or 1 so you might still want to wrap it if you really need a proper bool)